# Retrieving user's roles or claims in Windows 8

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

One of the requirements for the 70-484 exam (Windows 8 apps) is to retrieve user's roles or claims - what is the correct way to do that given the absence of `WindowsIdentity` and `WindowsPrincipal` classes in the .NET Metro profile (there are only `IIdentity` and `IPrincipal` interfaces available for a Windows 8 application but no classes implementing them)?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are looking for? Peter has very eloquently placed links below that are from official sources.

Comment: `ClaimsIdentity` class is not available for Windows 8 apps - it's not included in .NET Metro profile

Answer (score 1):

For claims/roles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.claimsidentity.claims.aspx

Credentials: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx

and if you need to authenticate the user: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.ui.credentialpicker.aspx